# Magento 2 layered navigation price filter issue

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, price, layered-navigation

Price filter show negative pricing like -1000- -01 and  so on

I have some configurable products in Magento 2 and it shows negative pricing in the layered navigation filter.

Please find the screenshot attached
[image: layered navigation issue]

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Goto file in vendor `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Price`

and change the code aroun line 206

```
$select->columns(
    [
        'min_price' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('io.min_price'),
        'max_price' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('io.max_price'),
        'tier_price' => 'io.tier_price',
    ]
);
```

and run reindexing.

Comment: Magento issues #7367, #14443

Comment: Bad answer because you never should edit `vendor` files.